# Can i read environment variable from Azure App Settings by using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable method?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, environment-variables, azure-app-configuration

I am adding Firebase SDK to the server.

The first step is to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable,

so I set the environment variable in the [Azure Service -> Configuration -> App Setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal).

I checked environment variables from [kudu](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/azure/app-service/resources-kudu) too.

And I tried to get an environmental variable from my ASP.NET app using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable method,

but It returns null and all the other environmental variables of the app settings return null too.

My project is built with .NET Framework 4.8 and MVC5.

Is there any information about this?

```c#
using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Nest;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Syndication;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Xml;

namespace ---.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ActionParams param)
        {
            ...

            var appsettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
            var local = appsettings["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"];
            var production = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
            ViewBag.localEnv = local;
            ViewBag.productionEnv = production;

            return View("Home", "Index");
        }
```

This project is from my company, so i blocked some information and the language is korean.

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the source code line of `GetEnvironmentVariable` method?

Comment: Please refer [.NET Framework app with Azure App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-dotnet-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to get the Azure Environment variables in my Environment.
Please check the below workaround.

- Created a .NET Framework App with MVC.
- Installed the below NuGet Packages

```cs
Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureAppConfiguration
Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
```

***Steps to Install NuGet Package***

Right Click on the Solution Explorer => Manage NuGet Packages => Search in the Browse tab

[image]

- In Web.config file => Under Configuration section add the below settings

```cs
 <configSections>
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
      <add name="DefaultEnvironment" mode="Greedy" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.EnvironmentConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment" />
    </builders>
  </configBuilders>
 
  <appSettings configBuilders="DefaultEnvironment">
    <add key="GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" value="Set via an environment variable - for example, dev, test, staging, or production connection string." />   
  </appSettings>
```

- Add the New `App setting` in Azure Web App `Configuration` Section.
  [image]
- Initially local `web.config` file contains the `appsettings` with some default value. Now I will override the value with Azure App Service Setting.
- In `HomeController`, write the below code.

```cs
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var appsettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
            var local = appsettings["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"];
            var production = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
            ViewBag.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = local;
            ViewBag.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS1 = production;
            return View();
        }
```

- I am able to get the Environment variable by using both

```
var appsettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
appsettings["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"];
and 
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
```

- In Home => Index.cshtml, add the below snippet somewhere in the file

```cs
 <h2> @ViewBag.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS - Local Settings</h2>
 <h2> @ViewBag.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS1 - Production Settings</h2>
```

***Local App Output***
[image]

***Published App OutPut  :***
[image]

- As you can see local settings are overridden by Azure App Settings.

References taken from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-dotnet-app)

Comment: hi, firstly thank you for the comment. it was very helful. so i can get local environment variables (e.g. appsettings["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"];). but i can't still get it from Azure App Settings. i installed all packages and did it exactly same, but it doesn't work. what can i check?

Comment: Could you please share the image of you Azure App settings?

Comment: I edited my question. Please check it.

Comment: What about your `web.config`? Have you added the configSections under configuration tag ?

Comment: In Your controller actionmethod you have async Task<> ? Remove it once and check.

Comment: Have you deployed your WebApp?

Comment: yes, i added config well and async Task is just return type of action, so i think it has anything to do with this. and yes i have deployed my webapp. i can only see local env string ("Set via an ~~") in deployed one and local one.

Comment: i have a question, isn't your reference about Azure App Configuration? isn't there difference between Azure App Configuration and Azure App Settings ?

Comment: hey, i solved this problem. I set up the app settings for another web app.. it was my mistake. Thank you for the comment so much!

Comment: And i deleted the other packages from [your references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-dotnet-app), but it worked well. So I think that packages is not necessary.

Comment: You can define settings that can be shared by multiple apps using Azure App Configuration.Azure App Settings are only for a particular web app, which overrides the existing environment variables.

Comment: oh, i got it. I will apply Azure App Configuration later. Thank you again.