# ASP.NET Core environment variable from Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

I'm working with .NET Core 6.0, my app is deployed to Azure.

I want to get access to environment variables in Azure from my code.

I created the key value in Azure:

[image]

When I try to access it using this code snippet:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BROKER_IP")
```

or

```
_conf["BROKER_IP"])
```

(`IConfiguration` is injected in the constructor), it is working when i run the program locally(able to get environment variable from my local PC), but when deployed to Azure (as an App Service), it doesn't return any value.

How can I access it from my API?

Part of my `program.cs` looks like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;
builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

I added this line :

```
builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

but I still have the same issue.

Thank you

Comment: Odd, I just created a `dotnet new webapp` pushed it to azure app service and can confirm, that an environment variable that is set locally, does not show up, when defined as an app setting in the configuration blade.

Comment: Thank you Marco, I mean that when i run the program locally , i can access the environment variables on my local pc but i  need to get the variable when the app is deployed on Azure (that is where i'm not getting any value)

Comment: Yes, same here. I set `ViewData["brokerip"] = _configuration["BROKER_IP"]`. Worked locally, but not when pushed to Azure.

Comment: Could you please share your `appsettings.json` file ?

Comment: Please refer similar kind of issue in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73541668/19648279)

Answer (score -1):

You just need to inject IConfiguration to your controller. I don't change any code in Startup.cs or Program.cs file. And it works for me.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;



   public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _config = config;
    }

   public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //ViewData["aa"] = "Learn about";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet("getKey")]
    public IActionResult GetTestKey()
    {
       string aa = _config["testKey"] ==null ? "test in local" : _config["testKey"].ToString();
        return Ok(aa);
    }
}
```

**Test Result**

[image]

[image]