# Net Core application not reading ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-configuration, asp.net-core-7.0

I deployed an ASP.NET Core 7 application to Linux Web Application in Azure.

When I access the URL I get an Application Error and the Logs shows:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
The configuration file 'settings..json' was not found and is not optional.
```

It seems it is missing the Environment value so it should be:

```
settings.production.json
```

In the Azure Application Service Configuration I have:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT",
    "value": "production",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

And the application `Program.cs` code is:

```
Serilog.Log.Logger = new 

Serilog.LoggerConfiguration()
  .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Verbose)
  .CreateBootstrapLogger();

try {

  Serilog.Log.Information("Starting up");

  WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions { 
    Args = args, 
    WebRootPath = "webroot" 
  });

  builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("settings.json", false, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"settings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", false, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

  // Remaining code
```

Am I doing something wrong or something change in Net 7?

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73538978/can-i-read-environment-variable-from-azure-app-settings-by-using-environment-get

Comment: Why do I need to use Azure App Configuration Store? I had this working fine in previous NET Core applications. And I am using NET Core.

Comment: As Specified in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-connection-strings), Storing the connection strings in Azure app Service configuration section is used to run the web application in cloud with production settings and storing the `web.config` files used to debug/run locally with the development settings.

Comment: Review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0. Note that environment variables are case sensitive in Linux, as opposed to Windows. Should use "Production", though this is the default and doesn't need to be specified. In Azure, configuration should be provided through the configuration of the app service, not a JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

In short, this problem occurs because the `settings.production.json` file was not included at the time of release.

We can verify this by uploading the 'settings.production.json' file to the scm site. The URL is `https://your_appname_azurewebsites.net/newui` .

[image]

**Solution:**

1. Official doc : [Include files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-7.0#include-files)
2. Sample： [Use ResolvedFileToPublish in ItemGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67206074/7687666)